# Indonesia or Malaysia tourist visa for Colombian citizen in India

Tags: tourist-visas, indonesia, malaysia, colombia, colombian-citizens

How can a Colombian citizen apply for tourist visa for Indonesia in India. We would like to plan a 2 week vacation there. Is e-visa a possibility?

Same question for Malaysian tourist visa.

Answer (score 2):

Malaysia: a Colombian national is not eligible for an e-visa https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/visa/evisa.html. Apply for a visa at any Malaysian Representative Office abroad https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/visa/apply-for-visa.html

Indonesia: Non-Indian nationals who are non-residents in India are encouraged to apply for Indonesian visa at the Indonesian Embassies/Consulates in their home countries prior to their visit to India. http://evisa.kbri-newdelhi.go.id/